# Selectize: Don't filter remote source

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I want to use selectize as an autocomplete for a remote source of information.

Currently looks like filtering results is mandatory (for example by setting searchField), but in this case makes no sense, since it's already filtered. I don't want to filter again, I just want to show the results.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378962/how-can-i-disable-automatic-filtering-in-selectize-js-built-in-plugin-modil?